# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 after the make command

Tags: makefile

I want to download LDBlockShow(https://github.com/BGI-shenzhen/LDBlockShow/) by git.

However, when I run the command

```
./configure
```

I received an error
`configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs`

So I add --host and try again

```
./configure --host=arm
```

It succeeds, but when I run next command

```
make
```

I received error report like this :

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:272: LDBlockShow] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/sherlock/Downloads/LDBlockShow'
make: *** [Makefile:178: all] Error 2
```

My operating system is macOS 10.14.6.

I don't know how to fix it, could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Follow the requirements listed in the README. This is not a Git issue, this is a matter of installing the right software on your host system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem has been resolved by editing the file make.sh. I changed line 30 "g++" to "g++ -std=c++11"  then run the command "sh make.sh"